# How to print hindi text returned from Google Speech API - Python

Tags: python, google-speech-api

I am using Google Speech API in python. In project I'm converting hindi audio to text. And I'm succesfully getting transcribed text using `language_code="hi-IN" Hindi (India)`.

but when I print I get this:

[image]

If i copy it and paste it on browser I'm able to read it but **cant print it on terminal or in a file**. I tried this :

```
i=0
for result in response.results:
    print('Transcript: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].transcript))
    print('Confidence: {}'.format(result.alternatives[0].confidence))
    chat_txt = str(result.alternatives[0].transcript)
    ft = open("Response"+str(i)+".txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
    ft.write(chat_txt)
    ft.write(str(len(chat_txt)))
    ft.close
    i += 1
```

It just creates empty file

Comment: I tried that. It gives this `ft.write(chat_txt)
  File "C:\Users\Karan\Envs\GoogleCloud\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 0-2: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: Ok, it is actually not the file. the file is correct, your terminal doesn't understand hindi...

Comment: Someway to write it to a file?